# How to upload polygon shapefiles to my GPS?

Tags: qgis, gps

I used QGIS to create a table (*.shp) containing 3 polygons. These polygons represent "forbidden zones" that I would like to export to my Garmin GPSmap62st so once on the countryside, I'll can see my position directly besides these "forbidden zones".

Can you tell me how please?

Answer (score 2):

Try the programm GPSBabel (http://www.gpsbabel.org/). Save shp-file in KML file in QGIS, then open KML file in GPSBabel and save in file/deviсe for Garmin GPSmap62st. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried DNR Garmin?

http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html

It allows you to convert shapefiles to Garmin tracks and then display those tracks on your GPS.  Here's a helpful YouTube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNHI7tB8hQ8